# javascript/jquery dropdown menu selection not passing GET request

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

In my page I have a dropdown menu, and upon selection I want to pass a GET request. This GET request should (ideally) trigger a function from my views.py file and return some data (based on the selection) from my database. However, it doesn't seem like anything actually happens upon dropdown menu selection.

Here is my script that I wrote to trigger the GET request when a selection was made:

```
<!-- AJAX Call for dropdown menu selection -->

<script type="text/javascript">
var url = $('.dropdown-menu').attr('action');
$('.dropdown-menu-option').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: {
            class: $('.dropdown-menu-option').val()
            },
        success: function(result) {
            alert ('pass');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the code for my dropdown menu in my template:

```
<!-- Query based content for dropdown menu -->
            <select class="dropdown-content">
                {% if current_user_properties %}
                    {% for property in current_user_properties %}
                    <option class="dropdown-menu-option" value="{{property.id}}">{{property.name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <option>You don't have any properties</option>
                {% endif %}
            </select>
```

Lastly, here is the code for the function I wanna run in my views.py

```
def property_selected(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    selection = request.GET.get('class', None)
    if selection:
        selected_data = MeterData.objects.filter(property=selection).order_by(date)
        return selected_data
```

If anyone can help identify what I'm missing/doing wrong, that'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: You have a `'` missing after action

Comment: `class: $('.dropdown-menu-option').val()` should also be `class: this.value`

Comment: @Musa that was actually an error when putting the code into here, my actual code does have the missing quote, I've edited the question to reflect this. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

`$('.dropdown-menu-option')` returns a collection of html nodes, since there are many elements that match this selector.

So when you pass `$('.dropdown-menu-option').val()` to the `class` property of the data object of ajax options, you are not really passing the value of the selected option.

You can attach a onChange event on the `select.dropdown-content` and get the value of the selected option like this:

```
$('.dropdown-content').on('change', function(e){
    var selectedOption = $(this).find(':selected').val()
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: {
        class: selectedOption 
        },
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've made your suggested changes, but I still don't seem to be getting any alerts when I select something from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Can you log the request body that your python script is receiving?
 Because it seems like  a backend issue now.